# What is the difference between Nikon NCP and NP2 picture control files?

Tags: nikon, tone-curves

Every time I use **Picture control utility 2** from Nikon, the software keep asking to choose one of the Camera Compatibility mode (NCP and NP2) as shown here under.

my questions is:

1. What is the difference between those mode?
2. Nikon D3200 is compatible which which one of them?
3. how to upload my custom setting to my Camera?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering your questions directly:

1. Nikon came out with a new version of Picture Control that has a new file extension associated to it(NP2). Some of the main benefits are: Finer adjustment of each parameter in increments of 0.25 and compatibility with the new Picture Control Flat and new parameter clarity.
2. The D3200 is compatible with NCP, as it is about 2 years older than the D810 that first introduced NP2. As far as I can tell, as of January 2014 only the D810 and D750 fully support the NP2 file format and its associated benefits.
3. Custom Settings can be transferred to a camera *that supports custom Picture Controls* via memory card and registered in the camera(see the last image on the first link below for detailed example). Note that I am not 100% confident that your camera even supports custom upload of Picture Controls.

More information can be found in various articles on Nikon's website:

- http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/microsite/picturecontrol/adjustment/custom.htm
- https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/19109/~/picture-control-utility-2.0